# React passing props to child, cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm a new Redux learner following Coursera's full-stack course. I'm trying to pass props to child component Home and DishDetail, but running into an issue with "cannot read property filter of undefined". The default states are stored in one of the Reducers ./redux/dishes.js

MainComponent.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishDetailComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addComment, fetchDishes } from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return{
    dishes: state.dishes,
    comments: state.comments,
    promotions: state.promotions,
    leaders: state.leaders
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(addComment(dishId, rating, author, comment)),
  fetchDishes: () => {dispatch(fetchDishes())}
})

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchDishes();
  }

  render() {

    const HomePage = () => {
      return(
          <Home 
              dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
              dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
              dishesErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
              promotion={this.props.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]}
              leader={this.props.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
          />
      );
    }

    const DishWithId = ({match}) => {
      return(
          <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))[0]}
            isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
            errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
            comments={this.props.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))}
            addComment={this.props.addComment}
          />
      );
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/menu" component={() => <Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} />
          <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />
          <Route exact path="/contactus" component={Contact} />
          <Route exact path="/aboutus" component={() => <About leaders={this.props.leaders} />} />
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

Reducer dishes.js

```js
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const Dishes = (state = {
    isLoading: true,
    errMess: null,
    dishes: []
}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: null, dishes: action.payload}
        case ActionTypes.DISHES_LOADING:
            return {...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null}
        case ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, errMess: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be that this.props.dishes.dishes does not have a filter property or method.  Try console.log(this.props.dishes.dishes to see what's available.

Comment: Is it just a typo? should `this.props.dishes.dishes` be `this.props.dishes`? Seems like that's how you're accessing it elsewhere.